# How can I get specific cells to increase by one hour each hour based off another cells start time

Tags: google-sheets

Here is a sample sheet of what I'm trying to accomplish

Basically, I am trying to get Column C to increase by one hour each hour based off of Column E start time. So if Mark starts at 6 when I check at noon it would show 6 hours for him etc.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Mr3O0v_mCoEQhEBb1iPSayrE4yFlKevAdf-nXaZkKE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In your column C you can create a formula that references the current date time.

The formula I found in Google Docs is: HOUR(NOW()), which will pull the hour portion of the current datetime. The full formula would then be =HOUR(NOW())-E2 for the first cell in your worksheet.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank  you. 1 question though as I hadn't even considered it earlier, is there way to have it figure an hour lunch at specific times?

Comment: There are a few ways that you could do this. If you want to do a specific time for each lunch hour, then you could create an If statement such as (assuming F2 as the lunch hour field):    

=IF(HOUR(NOW())=F2,F2-E2,if(HOUR(NOW())-E2<5,HOUR(Now())-E2,Hour(Now())-E2-1))  

The nested if statements allow you to calculate different times both before, during, and after the lunch hour to accommodate for unpaid lunch breaks.